# Receiving ': No such file or directory' when trying to run my Python script for Baxter Robot in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, groovy, sublimetext2, ros, shebang

I'm very new to programming and I'm working with a Baxter Robot by Rethink Robotics.

I have been able to run other peoples' Python scripts through the terminal no problem.

I have created my own custom script using Sublime Text 2 and saved it as .py. However when I try to run it, I receive the ': No such file or directory' error. I have checked my code and it has an identical template (code structure) to the others that work.

My shebang is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I have compared the properties of the file to the others and they are exactly same, i.e it's definitely a Python file.

Have I missed something in Sublime? It's using the first version of Python but I'm under the impression that it shouldn't be the issue.

I'm using ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I'm completely new to this and all the answers I have found have not helped.

**Edit:**

**My command in Ubuntu terminal:**

[baxter - http://localhost:11311] leigh@leigh-System-Product-Name:~/ros_ws$ rosrun baxter_interface hole_setup.py

**Error:**

: No such file or directory

If I change the Python script to onethatworks.py, it initiates fine.

Comment: Is the error you're getting from the shell, or a Python exception? Can you show the full error message, and perhaps the command you're running to get it?

Comment: The error comes from the shell, after I have started my workspace and session. I have pasted my command and error into my question.

Comment: Is it placed in the same directory you're executing it? Does it have appropriate privileges? Have You tried: `chmod +x hole_setup.py`?

Comment: I just figured it out. I was writing the code through Sublime Text 2 on Windows. It had therefore saved with a Windows ending and I managed to change it to Linux through Gedit.